# sqlite converting milliseconds to HH:MM:SS.SSS

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, strftime

I have a column in the table that stores milliseconds as an Integer type in sqlite.  The millisecond timestamp is stores the time it took for certain event happen.  For example, it took 36 milliseconds for Action 1 occurred, the value 36 will be stored into the table.

I want to construct a SQL select statement that will format the millisecond timestamp to HH:MM:SS.SSS format, and so far I couldn't get it working.

Here's what the SQL query that I constructed.

```
select strftime('%H:%M:%f', table_foo.time/1000, 'unixepoch') as time from table_foo
```

The query result returned 00:00:00.000 where I was expecting to see 00:00:00.036 when the timestamp is 36 ms.

It appears that it is not showing the reminder properly.

Can someone points me what I did wrong? or what is the appropriate way to do what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following, replace int `1000` with decimal `1000.0`.

```
select 
  strftime('%H:%M:%f', table_foo.time/1000.0, 'unixepoch') as time 
from table_foo
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  I don't think it matter but I am using SQLiteStudio to connect to a file based SQLite 3 database and uses its built-in SQL editor to query the database.

Comment: @beyonddc are you still getting the same answer? did you try the above solution?

Comment: Yes, the results are identical.

Comment: @beyonddc Really? `select strftime('%H:%M:%f', 36/1000.0, 'unixepoch');` returns `'00:00:00.036'` for me...

Comment: @Shawn Yea, really but I looked a bit more.  Apparently I guess this is a feature of SQLiteStudio because when I use the sqlite via command line, it is displaying the decimal correctly.  So I guess problem is considered solve.  Thank you guys.